# grails <f:field> tabindex

Tags: grails, gsp

How can I specify the tabindex within the `<f:field>`?

In this example tabindex would not work.

```
<div>
  <f:field bean="${registerCommand}" property="email" tabindex="1"/>
</div>
```

I want to do it in the `<f:field>` declaration itself. I understand that there can be tricky JS solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Prefix the attribute name with widget- so

```
widget-tabindex="1"
```